# Removing duplicates from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query that will not return rows that have the same ID. I would also like to specify a primary row so that, in the event two rows have the same ID, the primary row will be returned. If no primary row is specified I would like to return the first row.

Here is an example of the database I would like to query.

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | primary | label |
+----+---------+-------+
| 1  |    Y    |   A   |
| 1  |         |   B   |  
| 2  |         |   C   |
| 2  |         |   D   |
| 3  |         |   E   |
+----+---------+-------+
```

Here is an example of the result I am trying to achieve

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | primary | label |
+----+---------+-------+
| 1  |    Y    |   A   |
| 2  |         |   C   |
| 3  |         |   E   |
+----+---------+-------+
```

I've been trying to use select distinct but I'm very unsure as to the direction to pursue to solve this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the first row"? The first according to the label alphabetically? If so, is the label always distinct?

Comment: I meant the first row as it exists in the database. The labels are just a way to distinguish the rows so it can be more easily noticed that rows with like ids only appear once in the result.

Comment: Without ordering by something "the first row as it exists in the database" is pseudo random depending on indexes/caching etc. It won't keep track of insertion order by itself.

Comment: Row order "as it exists in the database" shouldn't be taken into account because that can change depending on DB versions etc. In short - that's unstable solution :) Better order by label.

Comment: In my case it doesn't matter which one I take if they have duplicate ids and no primary has been specified but I'll definitely keep that in mind for the future. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subqueries would be more appropriate than DISTINCT in your case.

Try the below. Here is a demonstration of it getting your desired result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97fdd3/1/0

By the way, when there is no "primary" for the ID, this will choose the lowest label value for that ID. This is as others have stated more reliable than the 'order in the database'.

```
select *
  from tbl t
 where t.label = (select x.label
                    from tbl x
                   where x.primary = 'Y'
                     and x.id = t.id)
    or (not exists
        (select 1
           from tbl x
          where x.primary = 'Y'
            and x.id = t.id) and
        t.label = (select min(x.label) from tbl x where x.id = t.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you already got an answer, but you could also use a regular `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a 
LEFT JOIN mytable b
  ON a.id = b.id AND (
            a.label>b.label AND a.primary IS NULL AND b.primary IS NULL OR 
                                a.primary IS NULL AND b.primary='Y')
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbc9f/2).

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's good for my SQL learning to see multiople methods of accomplishing tasks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, 
       IFNULL(primaries.primary, '') AS primary, 
       IFNULL(primaries.label, secondary.label) AS label
FROM yourTable AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM yourTable
           WHERE primary = 'Y') AS primaries
ON a.id = primaries.id AND a.label = primaries.label
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, MIN(label) AS label
           FROM yourTable
           WHERE primary != 'Y'
           GROUP BY id) AS secondary
ON a.id = secondary.id AND a.label = secondary.label
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this works (not tested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      t1.id
     ,t2.primary
     ,t2.label
FROM table t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT id, primary, label
        FROM table
        GROUP BY id
        ORDER BY primary DESC, label ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) t2 ON t2.id=t1.id
```

Comment: Your subquery just returns one row, not one row for each `id`.